# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not working, below arte the specifications:

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

this  are the references:

```
<link href="../Bootstrap/DateTimePicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Bootstrap/DateTimePicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Below is the javascripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example').datetimepicker();

</script>
```

This is the body part of the page:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="example">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

got stuck from last 2 days, any support will be highly appreciated.
Please help a.s.a.p.

Comment: does it throw any errors to the console?

Comment: no, everything works fine, only the calender does not shows when the input is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply id "example" to textbox and not to div.

Refer below code:

```
<html>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="example" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#example').datetimepicker();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried above HTML code by creating a sample page it works. It might not be worked at your end due conflicting with your existing page JS.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed some libraries. I have added all of them right from cdnjs service in case you are not using bower, yarn or other package managers. The example below is full copy of the one that is on the documentation page and is working as expected.

```js
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, i think i missed the bower part.

Comment: you can choose my answer as long as it helped you